# How to establish a holding company's tree structure in R

Tags: r, tree, igraph

I want to establish a holding company's tree structure. My purpose is to calculate this network's density, parent company's centrality. I think to build an edge list may be a good choice (Upper companies: sources; lower companies: targets; upper companies' shares of lower companies: weights). However, my data set only has the parent's share control rights on every subsidiary. For example, the normal tree structure should represent an edge list that every row has source, target, and source's shares of target:

```
source  target  share
A   B   50
A   C   69
A   D   56
B   E   80
B   F   72
C   G   45
D   H   67
D   I   35
D   J   90
G   K   55
```

My data set has source and target information and A's share control rights on every subsidiary. In other words, my data misses the shares of intermediate subsidiaries.

```
source  target  A's share right on Target
A   B   50
A   C   69
A   D   56
B   E   50
B   F   50
C   G   45
D   H   56
D   I   35
D   J   56
G   K   45
```

I don't know if it is possible to build an approirate table to let igraph import and to calculate the density and centrality of the parent?

Comment: See `?graph_from_data_frame`: http://igraph.org/r/doc/graph_from_data_frame.html

Answer (score 0):

You can import your edgelist as a .csv and convert it into a graph with [graph.data.frame](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/igraph/docs/graph.data.frame)

```
library(igraph)
g<-read.csv(file.choose(),header=TRUE,sep=";")
g<-graph.data.frame(g)
#by default, the weights of your edges should be stored as an attribute here:
E(g)$edge_weight
```

Is it the result you were looking for?